# What core Node.js modules are substituted by the React Native packager?

Tags: node.js, react-native

Both Browserify and webpack are substituting (shimming) browser-safe implementations for Node.js core modules, such as crypto or http so they can be used in browser-running JS code:

[Browserify compatibility list](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#compatibility)

[webpack compatibility list](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser)

Is there a similar list for the React Native packager?

I expect modules like crypto can be shimmed with the same substitutes as in Browserify, but what about tcp? You can't use it in the browser, but it can be bridged from native code on RN.

Comment: The reason I am putting this as a comment rather than an answer is because I have not successfully tried this yet.
However, it looks like the rn-nodeify module is made for this purpose. https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-nodeify

Comment: From a design viewpoint, if we reference a node module that tries to pull the Node core packages into our ReactNative project, are we using a module we shouldn't be using? Is there something we should be avoiding so that we don't encounter this problem?